# CPLEX: how to use array in summation?

Tags: arrays, sum, cplex

Integer programming.
I try to model the following constraint in Cplex:

∑*i   ∑*(τ=s-Dur(i)+1)to s    x_(i,r,t,τ)  ≤1,          ∀r,∀t,∀s〗

where x_(i,r,t,s) is the decision variable. 
The variable τ=s-Dur(i)+1 is used as auxiliary variable.
It is not possible to model this sum including an array. Thank you.

```
 range I = 1..operations;
 range J = 1..surgeons;
 range T = 1..timeBlock;
 range S = 1..timePeriod;
 range R = 1..room;

int Duration[I] =...;


//DVars
dvar int assignment[I][R][T][S] in 0..1;

//Objective function

maximize sum (i in I, r in R, t in T, s in S) (Duration[i] * assignment[i][r][t][s]);


// constraint
forall (r in R, t in T, s in S)
{
sum(i in I, s-Duration[i]+1 in s) (assignment[i][r][t][s-Dur[i]+1]) <= 1;
}
```

Comment: You probably need to do some preprocessing to create different sets and subsets of values to use as index sets instead of the current way you are writing your sum.

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite your constraint into:

```
sum(i in I: s-Duration[i]+1 in S) (assignment[i][r][t][s-Duration[i]+1]) <= 1;
```

And:

```
int operations=2;
int surgeons=3;
int timeBlock=2;
int timePeriod=2;
int room=4;
range I = 1..operations;
range J = 1..surgeons;
range T = 1..timeBlock;
range S = 1..timePeriod;
range R = 1..room;

int Duration[i in I] =i;


//DVars
dvar int assignment[I][R][T][S] in 0..1;

//Objective function

maximize sum (i in I, r in R, t in T, s in S) (Duration[i] * assignment[i][r][t][s]);

subject to
{
// constraint
forall (r in R, t in T, s in S)
{
sum(i in I: s-Duration[i]+1 in S) (assignment[i][r][t][s-Duration[i]+1]) <= 1;
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this solves the previous error. However, in order to have the right functionality I need the following:                                                    `forall (r in R, t in T, s in S)
{
sum(i in I: s-Duration[i]+1 in s) (assignment[i][r][t][s-Duration[i]+1]) <= 1;
}`                                                                                                                       the S being replaced by s, since I need the s given by the forall in the sum. Is this possible? Thank you.

Comment: sum(i in I: s-Duration[i]+1 in s) does not mean anything since s is a value and not a range nor a set. Do you mean in s..TimePeriod instead ?